# Can I trigger a double click with a single click in a form input[type="file"]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form `input` for submitting a file and I styled it because I didn't like the native style. Now, I have a single button that when clicked, it opens up the dialog to select the file. It works fine with a single click on Firefox and Chrome but it doesn't work in IE. The *button* needs a double click to open up the dialog in IE.

I have tried to trigger a double click with a single click using jQuery:

```
$("input").click(function() { 
    $(this).dblclick(); 
});
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other approach to trigger a double click for IE?

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HAaFb/

Comment: What version of IE are you trying to support?

Comment: The main question is: why does it need a double click in IE? That might be fixed. A file input is usually made of two parts: something that looks like a text input, and a button. In IE and only IE, the former is triggered by a double click, the latter by a single click.

Comment: @DoubleGrass I hide the button because it's ugly, I created a pseudo element and I keep the input hidden to click and open the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer isn't to trigger a dblclick, but to make file dialog opening with IE... Right? So i think the soluce would be to trigger a click on the file input (wich will be hidden?)

```
$("#formId").find("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
```

In your fiddle, I do this :

```
$("input").click(function() { 
    $('input[type="file"]').click(); 
});
```

I try this

```
$('input[type="file"]').hide().parent().append($('<span />').attr('class', 'filebutton').text('Upload'));
$(".filebutton").click(function() { 
    $('input[type="file"]').click(); 
});
```

With this CSS

```
form {
    color:#666;
}
.filebutton {
    content:'upload';
    font:small-caps 15px Georgia;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    width:100px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:20px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
}

.filebutton:hover {
    background-color:#f3f3f3!important;
    color:#c00;
     cursor : pointer;
}
```

And it work's...

Comment: When I first inserted your 1st script the dialog opened as soon as the document loaded. I thought this could be it but what I need is to open the dialog with a single click. Your 2nd piece of code seemed promising but for some reason it doesn't work in IE9.

Comment: The problem is that with your solution, the first click in IE just give the focus to the button... And i d'ont know how to fix it for now!

Comment: That is why I'm trying to trigger a 2nd click after the 1st click.

Comment: If you just wan't a code to work, use the code in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HAaFb/16/). (or above)

Comment: Just perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for your effort JoDev!

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this:

```
var count=0;
$("input").click(function(e) { 
    count++;
    if(count==2){
         count=0;
    }else{
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/HAaFb/1/

http://jsbin.com/ukotit/17/edit

Comment: Tested in IE9 and it doesn't open the dialog with a single click.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered that the jQuery file upload demo page actually repositions the file input field (while "hidden") so that the Browse button sits nicely within the region of the "Add files" button. And so when you click on that button with IE 8/9/10 it opens up with a single click.

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

In the one CSS I see:

```
.fileinput-button input {
...
right: 0px;
...
transform: translate(300px, 0) scale(4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

File inputs are an native/ActiveX component in IE and therefore can't have events performed on them - same for select inputs.

What really do you need the double click for?

Comment: This is exactly what I've done, if you check the demo. However, I want to simulate a double click only for IE.

Comment: I want to open the default dialog for choosing the file to upload. This can be done either by clicking on browse button, which is hidden in this case, or by double-clicking the input field.

Comment: You're going to need to reposition the browse button, as I mentioned below. It won't be possible to enact a double click on the input field due to the limitations of ActiveX components. As the browse button = 1 click, just change it's positioning and test it in 'opaque' view.

Comment: +1 for your suggestion. This was going to be my next move if I couldn't find a js solution. However, I wanted to avoid repositioning the button because buttons differ from browser to browser.

Comment: Use the Paul Irish IE classes code for classes used in the HTML element - that is the one thing that is 100% reliable and doesn't rely on user agent regexps: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm probably late to the party, but just in case anyone else stumbles upon this post, I was able to solve a similar issue with this:

```js
$("#uploadInput").bind('mousedown', function (event) {
    $(this).trigger('click')
});
```

Worked on both IE10 & IE11.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").click(function() { 
    $(this).trigger('dbclick');
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't trigger a double click in IE

Answer (score 0):

I haven't check this but I imagine you would need to use something like this:

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
  $(this).trigger('dblclick');
});
```

I hope thats not dumb, haha.

Comment: I've tried every variation of triggering a double click but still it doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

It's your CSS... if you disable opacity and the clip stuff in IE, you will see that the actual browse button is over to the right.

Make sure that filter:opacity is not used in IE9, that one worked for me. JSFiddle doesn't work in IE7/8 so I couldn't test those.