# JQuery Single click as a double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is a possibility to perform single click as a double click?

```
jQuery(document).on("click",function (t) {
     if (n == 1) {      
        // Single click as a double click
     }
});
```

Comment: Explain the issue you're trying to fix in the question, this is a wrong approach that will never work as per comment on alex's answer.

Comment: This may be your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343895/can-i-trigger-a-double-click-on-single-click-of-a-form-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
if (n == 1) {      
    e(this).trigger("dblclick");
}
```

This will trigger listeners for the `dblclick` event on the triggering element.

Comment: no, unfortunately it does not work. I have just Try it before.

The problem is I write with "insertAtCaret" in a text area and I would like him before but empty. If I do NOT textarea previously empty, single-click DOES. For empty and write, do I need to double click.
`code` e(document).on("click",function (t) {
 var n = e("#output").text();
         if (n == 1) {                        
 e(this).trigger("dblclick");
        var r = e("#eltreeCSSSel").text();
 e("#objectSelectVar").val("");
        e("#objectSelectVar").insertAtCaret(r);

Comment: Is this English? I didn't understand 90% of what you said. Triggering double click will not be like double clicking on it. It only triggers the double click function if you have one. In addition the code thet alex gave you should be t(this).trigger("dblclick"); or your function should be function(e){...